# An empty line/spacing in \title

Tags: titles

I am writing a thesis and this is what I have in my title:

```
\title{ {Trading Strategies Performance and Risk Evaluation Methodologies Investigation} \\
        {\large Institution} \\
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{inst_logo.jpg}} \\
        {\medium Supervisor: Prof Someone} \\
        \hfill \break
        \hfill \break
        \hfill \break
        {\small A dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment
of the requirements for the degree of}
        }
```

Now, the \hfill \break does work but I get errors in my latex file. Is there a better way to create an empty line?

Comment: Instead of `\hfill\break` try `\vspace{3\baselineskip}` ... however, your title use is unusual. For this is intended `titlepage`. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation.

Comment: Better have a look at [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)